# Recibir datos en vista - Yajra DataTables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatables, laravel-blade

Necesito enviar un dato a través del método `render()`, sin embargo no sé cómo recibirlo en la vista. Aquí está mi código (el `print_r($datos)`me genera error: `Undefined variable: datos`):

Controlador: **InventoryDetailReportController.php**

```
class InventoryDetailReportController extends Controller
{

    public function index (InventoryDetailDataTable $dataTable, Request $request, $inventario='') {

        $datos = array();
        array_push($datos, $inventario);
        return $dataTable->with('inventario', $inventario)->render('vista-reporte-inventario', $datos);

    }

}
```

Vista: **vista-reporte-inventario.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

{!! $dataTable->table() !!}
{!! print_r($datos) !!}

@endsection

@push('scripts')
/** Aquí van los scripts de datatables */
{!! $dataTable->scripts() !!}
@endpush
```

Intenté acceder a los datos con `$dataTable->datos` pero no me funcionó. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes las opciones **addColumn** y **editColumn** que posiblemente te valgan para lo que quieras.

Por ejemplo

```
DataTables::of($datos)
    ->addColumn('acciones', function ($dato) {
            return '<div style="background-color: #fff;height: 20px;"></div>'; // Añade una nueva columna
        })->editColumn('color', function ($dato) { // Edita la columna con nombre color
            return '<div style="background-color: ' . $dato->color . ';height: 20px;"></div>';
        })->make(true);
```